# Android-GPS ACCURACY_HIGH Criteria make my app crash

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I'm testing an app, that pick current position, and screen it on a widget. I'm using this function, but when i try to change accuracy to HIGH, all is crashing!

```
    private void startListening(){
        AppLog.logString("Service.startListening()");

        final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        final String bestProvider = manager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        if (bestProvider != null && bestProvider.length() > 0) {
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 500, 10, listener);
        }
        else {
            final List<String> providers = manager.getProviders(true);

            for (final String provider : providers) {
                manager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 500, 10, listener);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your AndroidManigest.xml file:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```